Lenovo Think Pad/windows 10 External Sound Recording Directions-
I am trying to make my Thinkpad Laptop work as a sound recorder that I could use to transfer the recorded sound files to a USB.  I would like to know if this is possble with my thinkpad.  Thanks.  mbp

your laptop likely has a built in microphone, especially if you have a webcam. Windows has an app known as sound recorder. Type those words into the search bar near your start button and it should appear. You can press the record button to begin, the stop button to end. There will be a save option in the menu. You can specify that it be saved to the flash drive.
If you require automatic operation, please edit your post to reflect this and any other specific aspects you require.

In addition to any built-in Windows sound recording apps, there are many third-party alternatives, such as Audacity (https://support.audacityteam.org/basics/recording-your-voice-and-microphone), VLC (https://www.wikihow.com/Record-Audio-with-VLC), etc.
